# What are the differences between these GAE libraries?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Throughout the Google App Engine documentation for Go, they use libraries interchangeably. Here's an example:

```
import "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
import "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
```

Which of these libraries should I use and what are the key differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cloud.google.com/go/datastore is a client library for the Cloud Datastore rest API (available from anywhere).

google.golang.org/appengine/datastore is part from App Engine API (available only from App Engine).

Comment: So if I'm using the App Engine standard environment, I should be using the appengine one?

Comment: Yes, it's should be faster. But you could use the first one as well.

Comment: I would also add that, if you want freedom to move your app in the future to GCE, other cloud provider, to your own server, etc. then avoiding using any App Engine API would be a good idea. Otherwise, I would stay with the native one.

Comment: IMO, I started using app engine stuff for app engine and memory leaks started going away (from some client context leak).